# Returning an average value of results

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

We have a system that is storing 1000's of readings per hour from various sensors.  These values are getting sent into a .net chart module.  It works, but when you view several days worth of data, there is basically 10's of thousands of results getting pumped into the chart and it's slow to process them all.  As a quick fix, I set it up to group and average all the results into an hourly bucket by breaking the Date column apart down to the hour (stripping out the minutes & seconds).  This works far faster but I want it to get better.  Here's the currently (bulky) query:

```
SELECT Value, CAST(CAST(yr AS char(4)) + '/' + CAST(mth AS char(2)) + '/' + CAST(dte AS char(2)) + ' ' + CAST(hr AS char(2)) + ':00:00' AS datetime) AS Date FROM (SELECT AVG(Value) AS Value, DATEPART(year, Date) AS yr, DATEPART(month, Date) AS mth, DATEPART(day, Date) AS dte, DATEPART(hour, Date) AS hr FROM SensorReadings WHERE (SensorID='15') AND (Date >= DATEADD(hour, - 336, getutcdate())) GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Date), DATEPART(month, Date), DATEPART(day, Date), DATEPART(hour, Date)) AS derivedtbl_1 ORDER BY date
```

This can return a few thousand results.  It still doesn't seem efficient  to have the chart module that may be only 300px wide, attempt to plot 1000's of points that basically would overlap.

My question is: is there a way to tell SQL to return only 300 results and have it average the Value and Date columns?   Crudely something like "Select only 300 avg(value) as Value, ave(date) as Date from SensorReadings order by Date"

Thanks!

Comment: You can use TOP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 to select the most recent values. If your most recent values are at the bottom of the table, you might need to do an ORDER BY ID ASC or DESC to get the latest data at the top of the table. Sadly I don't have an MSSQL installation currently to test it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two techniques for filtering results by a certain number of rows. In the Select statement simply add at the beginning  TOP (300) to limit the number of rows. If you want to use mathematical percentages then you can use TOP (2) PERCENT. Alternatively offset and fetch can be used to filter between results.

For the query construction is it possible to not used a derived table for the from statement and directly ready from sensor readings? You could just use the avg function on the columns in the primary select statement. If you have a sample output of rows from sensorreadings that would be helpful. Select top (5) * from sensorreadings.

Answer (score 0):

This will work - it splits the range into even segments by number of readings:

```
DECLARE @Partitions INT = 300;

WITH AllValues AS
(  SELECT Value,Date,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY Date asc)
   FROM SensorReadings WHERE (SensorID='15')
)
SELECT AverageValue = AVG(Value),
       AverageTime = DATEADD(second,AVG(CAST(datediff(second,'1/1/2000',Date) as BIGINT)),'1/1/2000')
FROM AllValues
GROUP BY RowNum / @Partitions
ORDER BY RowNum / @Partitions
```

Note that you can't take an average of a datetime; but you can take the average of the number of seconds since a given time.

Comment: Thanks, this was close enough to get me pointed in the right direction.  I'll post my final solution which I'll post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark above for getting me in the right direction.  Here is the final SQL that I got to work.  I first needed to determine the total number of rows to get the proper number of times to divide the Row_Number.  This has made a HUGE improvement with the site performance!

```
Declare @Partitions int
select    @Partitions=  count(value)/300 +1
from SensorReadings
WHERE     (SensorID = '31') and date>'4/1/2018';
WITH AllValues as
(
SELECT     Value, Date, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date 
ASC)/@Partitions
FROM         SensorReadings
WHERE     (SensorID = '31') and date>'4/1/2018'
)
SELECT AverageValue = AVG(Value),
   AverageTime = DATEADD(second,AVG(CAST(datediff(second,'1/1/2000',Date) as 
BIGINT)),'1/1/2000')
FROM AllValues
GROUP BY RowNum 
ORDER BY RowNum
```